# Difference between valueOf() and String.format()

Tags: java, double

Why are the values of `String.valueOf(5.6d + 5.8d)` and `String.format("%f", 5.6d + 5.8d)` diffrent?

`String.valueOf(5.6d + 5.8d)` will print "11.399999999999999".
`String.format("%f", 5.6d + 5.8d)` will print "11.400000".

Why is it so?

Edit: The question differs to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) , because `String.format()` round up (see answers)

Comment: Ah okay. And the "11.99999999" is just a precision-issue of double?

Comment: @GhostCat I don't believe this is a duplicate, as `String.format` is different from `String.valueOf(double)` in this case due to rounding, which I believe is what OP was interested in.

Comment: Yes floating point is just a finite approximation - without precision. 0.6 = 3/5 and 0.8 = 4/5 cannot be presented finitely with binary digits 0, 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of *Format Strings* for [String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec):

> If the precision is less than the number of digits which would appear after the decimal point in the string returned by Float.toString(float) or Double.toString(double) respectively, then the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm.

By default, `String.format("%f", ...)` uses `6` decimal digits of precision; because this is fewer digits than what would appear when used by `Double.toString(double)` (which is equivalent to `String.valueOf(double)`), then the value is rounded as specified above.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the explanation.

1. The result of `5.6d + 5.8d` is not exactly `11.4` due to binary floating point representation, precision and rounding issues; see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for explanations of why that is so.  (And no, it isn't broken!)
2. The reason that `String.valueOf` and `String.format` are outputting different answers *for the same `double` value* is down to the respective specifications:

   For `valueOf`:

   > *"How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double."*

   The `double` value is closer to `11.399999999999999` than `14.0` so the output is the former.

   For `format`:

   > *"If the conversion is 'e', 'E' or 'f', then the precision is the number of digits after the decimal separator. If the precision is not specified, then it is assumed to be 6."*

   When you round `11.399999999999999` to 6 digits of precision after the decimal point you get `11.40000000`.

(The above quotes are from the Java 9 javadocs.)